# Server 2016 where is Magic packet registry setting

Tags: windows-server-core, wake-on-lan, suspend

Does anyone know where "Only allow a magic packet to wake this computer" setting has moved to in 2016-core?

This 2016-core server can be kept awake by continuous pings or if I let it suspend it can be woken by a Magic Packet but does not wake on ping or any other network packets.

On Server 2012 device manager for the NIC there are three check-boxes under the Power Management tab:

```
1).    "Allow the computer to turm off this device to save power"
2).    "Allow this device to wake the computer"
3).        "Only allow a magic packet to wake this computer"
```

I have identified that these are stored in the registry hive:
HKLM\System\CCS\Control\Class{4D36e972-E325-11CE-BFC1...}\nnnn\PnPCapabilities (DWord)

Where:

```
24 - 1=off, 2=off, 3=off
16 - 1=on, 2=off, 3=off
0 - 1=on, 2=on, 3=off
256 - 1=on, 2=on, 3=on
```

I suspect that this setting is enabled by default, how do I disable it in Server-core?

Answer (score 0):

```
Set-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "Ethernet" -DisplayName "Wake on magic packet" -DisplayValue "Disabled"
```

To see the current values:

```
Get-NetAdapterAdvancedProperty -Name "*"
```

Comment: Unfortunately not, this does not seem to change the: "Only allow a magic packet to wake this computer" device manager behaviour.  




Have tried this out on a 2012 (server with a GUI) install and found that it relates instead to the NIC Advanced tab setting rather than the Power Management tab setting.

Comment: Is it possible that Server-Core simply doesn't support Power Saving at all?